# How to pass parameters to custom validation constraint in Symfony 2

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I'm working on a validation constraint that check if a url exist. I made it work, but I would like to be able to pass a parameters that say that my url can actually be empty and it would be O.K.

I know that you can pass parameters in some validation that comes with Symfony 2, for exemple:

```
Becyk\PublicBundle\Entity\ProduitsInfo:
    properties:
        file:
            - Image:
                mimeTypes: "image/png"
                mimeTypesMessage: "Que des images sous format le format png"
                minWidth: 175
                minWidthMessage: "175px de large précisément"
                maxWidth: 175
                maxWidthMessage: "175px de large précisément"
                minHeight: 165
                maxHeightMessage: "165px de haut précisément"
                maxHeight: 165
                maxHeightMessage: "165px de haut précisément"
```

So, I would like to do something like:

```
PublicBundle\Entity\Infos:
    properties:
        lien:
            - Url: ~
            - AdminBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContrainteUrlExist:
                canBeEmpty: true
        linkedin:
            - Url: ~
            - AdminBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContrainteUrlLinkedIn: ~
```

My validation classes look like this:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ContrainteUrlExist extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Cette adresse ne fonctionne pas.';
}
```

and:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

Class ContrainteUrlExistValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($url, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        //
        /*if(empty($url)&&$canBeEmpty)
        {
            return;
        }*/

        //Valide l'url
        if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false)
        {
            //Trouve l'host
            $hostname=parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

            //Tente de trouver l'adresse IP de l'host
            if (gethostbyname($hostname) !== $hostname)
            {
                //Cherche les données de l'entête
                $headers=get_headers($url);

                //Tente de trouver une erreur 404
                if(!strpos($headers[0], '404'))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                    ->setParameter('%string%', $url)
                    ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ContrainteUrlExist` you must defined public properties, then you can use them as parameters.